# Is my class going to lose its memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a class with two methods listed below.  I call them from another class in a function.  In this function I new up my class then call fireTorpedoContinued.  In C# everything would be great, but I started to think about it.  I'm not retaining the class anywhere and there seems to be nothing to stop it from going out of memory between fire torpedo and firetorpedo continued.  Does anything hold onto this class or do I need to retain it?  For example does the execute function class retain the class?  What if that was not there would I be in trouble?

```
- (void) fireTorpedoContinued
{
    [self.torpedoData.explosionSprite stopAllActions];
    CCPlace *placeAction = [CCPlace actionWithPosition:_endPoint];
    CCShow *showAction = [CCShow action];
    CCCallFunc *callFunctionDeathCheck = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self.deathCheckSelectorTarget selector:self.deathCheckSelector];
    CCFadeOut *fadeOutAction = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:1.0f];
    CCCallFunc *callfunctionAction = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self.completedSelectorTarget selector:self.completedSelector];

    CCSequence *sequenceAction = [CCSequence actions:placeAction, showAction, callFunctionDeathCheck, fadeOutAction, callfunctionAction, nil];
    [self.torpedoData.explosionSprite runAction:sequenceAction];

}

- (void) fireTorpedo
{
    [self.torpedoData.torpedoSprite stopAllActions];
    CCPlace *placeAction = [CCPlace actionWithPosition:_startPoint];
    CCShow *showAction = [CCShow action];
    CCMoveTo *moving = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2.0f position:_endPoint];
    CCHide *hideAction = [CCHide action];    
    CCAction *callCompletedFunction = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(fireTorpedoContinued)];

    CCSequence *sequenceAction = [CCSequence actions:placeAction, showAction, moving, hideAction, callCompletedFunction, nil];
    [self.torpedoData.torpedoSprite runAction: sequenceAction];
}
```

Comment: Can't really answer unless you post the code that instantiates and uses this class- the contents of a class are irrelevant to whether it is retained.

Comment: Good lord! Have you attached a torpedo launcher to your iPhone? :D Rob's quite right -- this is the wrong code to show us. Please post the code that uses the class, not the class itself.

Comment: i look forward to downloading your iTorpedo :P

Comment: Really need to put some more code, to exactly answer your question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little fuzzy, but everything you need to know is explained here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-BEHDEDDB